# If I have the same package name in Nexus private repo as it is in the npm publish repo, which one takes priority when I install?

Tags: nexus3

I am setting up nexus npm repository, and created npm-group = npm-private+npm-registry (proxy to npm offical registry).

It comes to me thinking that if I publish my own package and name it say "jest" to my private repo,
what happens if I do npm install jest? Does it take the private fake one or the one published in official site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use scopes for your  private packages. You prefix them with @yournamespace (for instance: `"name": "@yournamespace/jest"`), and you adjust your npmrc accordingly:

```
; Set a new registry for a scoped package
@yournamespace:registry=https://mycustomregistry.example.org
```

Using this scheme, you could use separate npm repositories, one for the proxy to the official npmjs repo, and one for your private packages.

Otherwise, if you override a package name, it will shadow the one that is proxified, so you will fetch your private package instead of the official one.

Comment: Thank you, I really like this approach, it gives me a peace of mind and don't need to worry about conflicts and you also answered me which one take precedence. Thank you!